# Is there EXCEPT analog in Slick 2.1 ORM?

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, slick, slick-2.0

I have such type of a query:

```
select1 union select2 except select3
```

All selects have joins and are mapped to single value. So the result of the whole query is a list of integers. In *Slick* there is a **union** method but there is no **except** method (or I couldn't find it). So I solved this like this (using *Slick* ans Scala methods):

```
(select1.union(select2)).list.filterNot(select3.list.contains)
```

Is there another way to create sql query with *EXCEPT* word or the same logic using *Slick* DSL?